# redirect to shopping cart page customer logged in to site

Tags: shopping-cart, register

after customer logged in  to our site, it's redirecting to "my account " page.

but i want to redirect to "shopping cart" page.

i reffered this link for

> [ Creating account = > Shopping cart  page]

now we need for

> "loogged in = > "shopping cart page

please help me to find solution

Comment: hi, you want this after customer register or customer loggin?

Comment: hi, i need only for customer register now.....

Comment: see thislink i will provide the solutioon http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/61108/get-user-credentials-with-an-observer-on-customer-register-success-event/61115#61115

Comment: did you provide the correct link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case,you can use event `customer_login` and

Condtion:

- fire `this event on frontend <frontend> area.`
- Basically when customer are loggedin success then the event is
  fire.Also and put a condition for current full action for
  `Mage::app()->getRequest()->getFullActionName()=='customer_account_loginPost'`
  because of Customer also register at checkout step

Then at  observer redirect to your shopping cart page using below
code:

```
Mage::app()->getResponse()
                        ->setRedirect($YOurUrl)
                             ->sendResponse();
```

**Config.xml code:**

```
  <global>
    <models>
      <magento>
        <class>StackExchange_Magento_Model</class>
      </magento>
    </models>
  </global>
<frontend><!-- area -->
    <events>
      <customer_login> <!-- identifier of the event we want to catch -->
        <observers>
          <customer_login_redirect> <!-- identifier of the event handler -->
            <type>model</type> <!-- class method call type; valid are model, object and singleton -->
            <class>magento/observer</class> <!-- observers class alias -->
            <method>redirectiontoCart</method>  <!-- observer's method to be called -->
          </customer_login_redirect>
        </observers>
      </customer_login>
    </events>
<frontend>
```

**Observer.php is :**

```
<?php
class StackExchange_Magento_Model{
public function redirectiontoCart(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        if(Mage::app()->getRequest()->getFullActionName()=='customer_account_loginPost'):
            Mage::app()->getResponse()
                            ->setRedirect($YOurUrl)
                                 ->sendResponse();

        endif;

    }
}
?>
```

Comment: i will try this....